# lambda expression for fetching data from mssql in python

Tags: python, for-loop, lambda

I have mssql table and i want to fetch few columns for some specific id's from that table using lambda function. Id is iterating over for loop.

Can you guide me to get the specific outcome so that I can fetch data of 1 id and append it to empty dataframe?

```
df=pd.DataFrame()

 for i in range(len(temp)): 
    query="""select Code, Date,Status,Category,Class,Quantity FROM table_name where Code= '""" + str(temp.loc[i,'Code'])+"'"
    new=pd.read_sql(query,conn)
    df = df.append(temp)   
    return df
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The output of the query can be easily converted to dataframe. why loop? if you pass the list to the query you get your result, then convert to a dataframe.

Comment: i have around 100 ids..in sql query i have mentioned where clause there i have to iterate over for loop .

Comment: just do a query where id = [those 100 ids]. The result can be converted to a dataframe easily.

Comment: The trick is to pass those 100 ids into the where clause. No need to loop. The where clause will be modified to be table_name where Code in (id1, id2, id3...)

Comment: Be aware that Date is a reserved word in MS SQL Server (and Code is in some other variants). I would rename some of those fields or surround them with square brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pratham, see the logic you need. You can use the `tuple` function that allows you to pass the list to the query text. The result of the query can be used to build a dataframe. Let me know if it works.

```
inilist =[4, 34, 6, 9, 0, 5]
t = tuple(inilist)
query = "select Code, Date,Status,Category,Class,Quantity FROM table_name where Code IN {}".format(t)
query
```

Results:

```
'select Code, Date,Status,Category,Class,Quantity FROM table_name where Code IN (4, 34, 6, 9, 0, 5)'
```